# LINQ - Group Join + Where clause

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two lists

```
var stores = new[] 
{
    new { Code = 1, Name = "Store 1" },
    new { Code = 2, Name = "Store 2" }    
};

var orders = new[] 
{
    new { Code = 1, StoreCode = 1, TotalValue = 4.12 },
    new { Code = 2, StoreCode = 1, TotalValue = 14.12 },
    new { Code = 3, StoreCode = 1, TotalValue = 24.12 }
};
```

OUTPUT desired

StoreName = Store 1 | TotalValue = 38.24

<s>LINQ to SQL</s> LINQ to Objects

```
var result = (from s in stores
              join o in orders on s.Code equals o.StoreCode into grp
              where o.TotalValue > 10 // error
              select new
              {
                  StoreName = s.Name,
                  TotalValue = grp.Sum(x => x.TotalValue)
              }).ToList();
```

Error: The name 'o' does not exist in the current context.

In this scenario, how to filter by order?

Comment: Deleting your question and re-posting it, word for word, just because it has gotten downvotes, is inappropriate and is likely to result in you being banned from asking questions in the future.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20707635/linq-group-join-and-where-clause#20707635

Comment: @Servy I did not know it. Sorry!

Comment: what has linq to sql got to do with linq on two arrays?

Comment: `orders.Select(o => new { StoreName = stores.Single(s => s.Code = o.Code).Name, s.TotalValue });`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = (from s in stores
              join o in orders.Where(x => x.TotalValue > 10) on s.Code equals o.StoreCode into grp
              select new
              {
                  StoreName = s.Name,
                  TotalValue = grp.Sum(x => x.TotalValue)
              });
```

Or this

```
var result = (from s in stores
              join o in orders on s.Code equals o.StoreCode into grp
              select new
              {
                  StoreName = s.Name,
                  TotalValue = grp.Where(x => x.TotalValue > 10)
                                  .Sum(x => x.TotalValue)
              });
```

Note that it's usually not necessary to call `ToList`, as this requires immediate evaluation of the query. Most of the time, leaving it as `IEnumerable<T>` is sufficient. Also, this will also return a row for 'Store 2', with `TotalValue = 0`. If you'd like to omit these rows as well, you can use something like this.

```
var result = (from s in stores
              join o in orders.Where(x => x.TotalValue > 10) on s.Code equals o.StoreCode into grp
              let totalValue = grp.Sum(x => x.TotalValue)
              where totalValue > 0
              select new
              {
                  StoreName = s.Name,
                  TotalValue = totalValue 
              });
```

Or this

```
var result = (from s in stores
              join o in orders on s.Code equals o.StoreCode into grp
              let totalValue = grp.Where(x => x.TotalValue > 10)
                                  .Sum(x => x.TotalValue)
              where totalValue > 0
              select new
              {
                  StoreName = s.Name,
                  TotalValue = totalValue 
              });
```